# Concatenate multiple existing dataframes using names of dataframes included in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, concatenation

actually I am economist and not a programmer, I hope there is a good Samaritan who can help me out.

I have a list called iShares:

```
iShares = ['IE0005042456', 'IE00B1FZS574', 'IE00B0M62Q58', 'IE00BF4RFH31', 'IE0031442068', 'IE00BGL86Z12', 'IE00BD45KH83']
```

Also I have a list of dataframes with identical structure:

```
Lookup_Sector_IE0005042456
Lookup_Sector_IE00B1FZS574
Lookup_Sector_IE00B0M62Q58
Lookup_Sector_IE00BF4RFH31
Lookup_Sector_IE0031442068
Lookup_Sector_IE00BGL86Z12
Lookup_Sector_IE00BD45KH83
```

I would like to concatenate these dataframes to only one data frame with the name Lookup_Sector. This is possible by hardcoding the names:

```
Lookup_Sector = pd.concat([Lookup_Sector_IE0005042456, Lookup_Sector_IE00B1FZS574, Lookup_Sector_IE00B0M62Q58, Lookup_Sector_IE00BF4RFH31, Lookup_Sector_IE0031442068, Lookup_Sector_IE00BGL86Z12, Lookup_Sector_IE00BD45KH83])
```

But what I rather would like to is not to hardcode and instead be more flexible and use the list iShares by first creating another list with the names of the dataframes, called Lookup_Sector_list:

```
Lookup_Sector_list = ['Lookup_Sector_' + i for i in iShares]
```

Then in the next step I would love to concetenate by using a for loop:

```
for i in Lookup_Sector_list:
    Sector = pd.concat([Lookup_Sector_list[i]])
```

If I do so I get an error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How can I concatenate the dataframes without hardcoding the names and instead using the list iShares?

TY so much in advance.

Comment: did you say you have a list? or you just have dataframes?

Comment: @onyambu Sorry, I didn't get your point. My english is not the very best, may be u can get more into details?

Comment: try `pd.concat([globals()['Lookup_Sector_' + i ]for i in iShares])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all your dataframes are in the global environment, You can select them using `globals()[dat]` and then concatenate them:

```
pd.concat([globals()['Lookup_Sector_' + i ]for i in iShares])
```

Comment: TY for your instant support, works fine!